# setting the values of AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_KEY using SQSConnectionFactory

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using `aws` `sqs` in my current project. I need to know how to set access key and secret key (to be read from a properties file) using `SQSConnectionFactory`.

Please find my code below:

```
public void createConnectionFactory() throws JMSException{
    try {
        SQSConnectionFactory connectionFactory = SQSConnectionFactory.builder()
            .withRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1))
            .withAWSCredentialsProvider(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider())
            .build();

            // Create the connection.
            SQSConnection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    }
    catch (JMSException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I tried searching methods through which I can set, but couldn't find any. How to proceed from here? Should I write another method for Basic Authentication and invoke it here or is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use the default credentials provider chain which allows to [supply credentials in multiple ways](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html)

In summary it allows for a very flexible configuration for both your development teams and when deploy to the cloud with multiple environments and [multi-region setup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-region-selection.html).

You can include the bean like this:

```
 <bean id="awsCredentialsProviderBean" class="com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain">
 </bean>
 <bean id="awsConnectionFactoryBuilder" class="com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSConnectionFactory$Builder">
     <property name="regionName" value="${aws.region}"/>
     <property name="numberOfMessagesToPrefetch" value="5"/>
     <property name="awsCredentialsProvider" ref="awsCredentialsProviderBean"/>
 </bean>
```

or use java

```
@Bean
public AWSCredentialsProviderChain awsCredentials() {
    return new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks , I found the mistake !

Here are the changes that I made and now its working fine

```
private BasicAWSCredentials credentials;

public void createConnectionFactory() throws JMSException,FileNotFoundException{
try {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(new FileInputStream("/src/main/resources/AwsCredentials.properties"));
        this.credentials = new   BasicAWSCredentials(properties.getProperty("accessKey"),
                properties.getProperty("secretKey"));

        SQSConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                SQSConnectionFactory.builder()
                        .withRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1))
                        .withAWSCredentialsProvider(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider())
                        .build();

        // Create the connection.
        SQSConnection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(credentials.getAWSAccessKeyId(),credentials.getAWSSecretKey());

    }
    catch (JMSException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow , working on my formatting skills . Thanks for the help!